# Imgur Anon API to Authenticated API

Tags: api, imgur

Im using imgur anon api key to upload a generated meme from a meme generator.

heres the js function:

```
function generate_meme(e) {
    $('#spinner-generate').show();
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").split(',')[1];
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        type: 'base64',
        key: api_key.val(),
        image: dataURL
    },
    dataType: 'json'
}).success(image_uploaded).error(image_upload_failed);
e.preventDefault();
return false;
}
```

As you can see it is using anon api. I want to do the same thing but with the authenticated api https://imgur.com/register/api so the images are uploaded to my imgur account, and are available in my album. What should i do?